# Problems with FriendlyId and parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, friendly-id

I am trying to change my urls from whatever.com/users/1 to whatever.com/users/jamie.Surname or whatever.com/users/jamie-Surname

I would quite like to eventually change to whatever.com/jamie.surname or whatever.com/jamie-surname but I thought it would be best to start of simple.

So I installed the friendly_id gem, starting simple I tried to just have it route to my first name with;

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      extend FriendlyId
      friendly_id :first_name
```

**However when I try to go to the url I am getting the error;**

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show

Couldn't find User without an ID

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:22:in `show'

Request
Parameters:
{"id"=>"jamie"}

**This line is the method in my users_controller where its throwing up the error**

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
        respond_to do |format|
        format.html 
        format.json { render json: @user }
    end
end
```

I can't seem to figure out a way to fix this.

Any help or suggestions/pushes in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This asciicast may help you -

http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast

Also note that it is important to note that which FriendlyId version you are using.

Check this for issues:

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/146